# How to convert sql mod to django orm?

Tags: django, orm, django-orm, modulo

The sql is:

```
select id from tableA where MOD(id,10)=1
```

database is mysql. How to covert this sql to django orm filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the **`%`** operator:

```
from django.db.models import F

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    id10=F('id') % 10
).filter(
    id10=1
)
```